# Error in getting to mysql prompt

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I installed MySQL and now I am trying to get into the prompt of MySQL with this command `mysql -host localhost -p` but I am getting this error:

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'ost' (2)

Does anyone of you know why I get this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used this command

```
mysql  -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-host` parameter for mysql - just the parameters `-h` or `--host=HOSTNAME` for specifying the hostname.

So use either:

- `mysql -h localhost -p`
- `mysql -host=localhost -p`

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql